# How to read data from Databricks DBFS using Rest API in csv or Excel format?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using Databricks Rest API to read datasets stored on DFBS. The output is coming in 64bit encoded format and in json format.
I need the output in tabular format which is easy to read.

Output of Rest Api:
{
"bytes_read": 4601,
"data": "U2VwYWxMZW5ndGgsU2VwYWxXaWR0aCxQZXRhbE"
}

output needed:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXh7g.png)

Comment: Are you sure there's no more output? Running that `data` value through a Base64 decoder gives part of the column names from your image, so it seems like there should be more information in the response.

Comment: The output was a bigger string. I shortened it for the sake of simplicity. I there a way to decode it and get a table structure in the in the API Itself.

Comment: Not sure. I'd guess is you base64 decoded the full string, you'd get the table in CSV form. Can't tell without the full string though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to download csv file,

jsonbody = {"path": dbfspath}

TOKEN  = "dapi....." # you can generate this token from users settings

response = requests.get('https://eastus.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/dbfs/read/', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % self.TOKEN }, json= jsonbody )

filedata =  json.loads(response.text)["data"]

with open(outputpath, "wb") as file:

```
  file.write(base64.b64decode(filedata))
```

Let me know if you need any other help